# Returning NULL and NOT NULL values in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to show NULL values and NOT NULL values for c.GUIDELINE_TEXT.  I've seen some examples but I'm not sure where to put it. When I use this code :

```
WHERE c.GUIDELINE_TEXT is NULL
```

I don't get any values returned. I haven't tried COALESCE as I'm not quite sure what that is or where to put it in my code. I do know that GUIDELINE_TEXT does have null values. I know I'm probably making some newbie mistake so if someone can point me in the right direction that would be nice. Thank you.

```
SELECT
    a.ORDER_NO,
    a.RELEASE_NO,
    a.SEQUENCE_NO,
    b.C_OPERATION_SEQUENCE as OP_SEQ,
    b.OPERATION_NO,
    b.OP_ID,
    c.GUIDELINE_TEXT
FROM
    ifsapp.SHOP_ORD a,
    ifsapp.SHOP_ORDER_OPERATION b,
    ifsapp.SHOP_ORD_WORK_GUIDE c
WHERE
    a.ORDER_NO = b.ORDER_NO 
    AND b.ORDER_NO = c.ORDER_NO
    AND a.RELEASE_NO = b.RELEASE_NO
    AND b.RELEASE_NO = c.RELEASE_NO
    AND a.SEQUENCE_NO=b.SEQUENCE_NO
    AND b.SEQUENCE_NO = c.SEQUENCE_NO
    AND b.OPERATION_NO = c.OPERATION_NO
    AND a.ORDER_NO = ('&Ord')
    AND a.RELEASE_NO = ('&Rel')
    AND a.SEQUENCE_NO = ('&Seq')
```

EDIT: An example of data.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bThuw.png)

An expected result would be that it pulls data also from blank columns of GUIDELINE_TEXT with the hopeful result that it will pull all order_no instead of just those that have text in GUIDELINE_TEXT column.

Comment: Are you using Oracle or MS SQL Server? Please don't tag products not involved...

Comment: Can you add some sample table data and expected result?

Comment: From the schema name it's IFS, which runs on Oracle

Comment: Yeah, it's IFS. Also being run on Oracle.

Comment: as you are not joining on GUIDELINE_TEXT the presence or absence of it should not affect your query.  Try it...run the select with and without select NVL(GUIDELINE_TEXT,'A value').  You should get the same number of results.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s I actually didn't write this code. I'm just filling in the gaps for code that's been written. I'm not too familiar with joins yet. But thank you for the guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing sample data this should show the presence of null values

```
SELECT
a.ORDER_NO,
a.RELEASE_NO,
a.SEQUENCE_NO,
b.C_OPERATION_SEQUENCE as OP_SEQ,
b.OPERATION_NO,
b.OP_ID,
NVL(c.GUIDELINE_TEXT,'Nothing to see, move along') AS GUIDELINE_TEXT
```

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) "NVL lets you replace null (returned as a blank) with a string".

COALESCE returns the first non null value from a list which is described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm).  Coalesce can be tricky to use if you have multiple values which might or might not be null. If your set of possible values can be arranged in order of likelihood of a non null value or you know for sure that all the values in the expression will be the same then it is very helpful.

Comment: If you would be so kind, can you explain to me what NVL means and why showing NULL values from the SELECT sequence works? I've only seen null value code in the WHERE statement.

Comment: Thank you, very much for explaining that.